# How to update AppleScript List "Forever"

Tags: macos, scripting, applescript, automator

Look at the following code:

```
set TheStringsQ1Happy to {"Fabulous", "Great", "Alright", "Excited", "Not Bad", "", "Decent", "Fine", "Awesome", "Bored", "Cool", "Sad", "Fantastic", "Alright", "Good", "Ok"}

set theResponse to the text returned of (display dialog "" default answer "" giving up after 5)

if TheStringsQ1Happy contains theResponse then 
    display dialog "That's Great!" 
else
    say "That term is not in my vocabulary. Would you like me to add it?" using "Tom" speaking rate 220
    set theResponseNotInVocabulary to text returned of (display dialog "" default answer "" giving up after 5)

    if theResponseNotInVocabulary is "Yes" then 
       set end of TheStringsQ1Happy to theResponse
       return TheStringsQ1Happy
   end if
```

Although I can update `TheStringsQ1Happy`, this update only lasts the span of the script. How can I change the code so that every time I run the script, it also contains the updated vocabulary?

For example, if I said "All Good", the computer would recognize that the vocabulary is not on the list, and would later update this list only for that instance. How can I make it so that "All Good" stays for every instance from now on?

Answer (score 1):

The following is strictly an example to help you with what you asked, not fix the broken code you posted.

If you run the following in Script Editor:

```
property theList : {1, 2, 3}
copy (count theList) + 1 to end of theList
log theList
```

You'll see `theList` as a `property` grow by 1 each time you run it, that is until the script is recompiled.

If you need absolute long term storage where nothing will be lost of anything added to theList, then you need to save to and retrieve from a disk file.

Answer (score 0):

*Variables* in AppleScript don't span outside the duration of execution of the script in which they are defined, as you've quite rightly noticed.

However, a *property* can, and will continue into subsequent executions of a script with the information left over from the previous execution.

Bear in mind, though, that a *property* will get reset (restored to its original value) each time the script is re-compiled (which happens whenever you make edits to it, or trigger it to compile manually).

With this in mind, change this line:

```
set TheStringsQ1Happy to {"Fabulous", "Great", "Alright", "Excited", "Not Bad", "", "Decent", "Fine", "Awesome", "Bored", "Cool", "Sad", "Fantastic", "Alright", "Good", "Ok"}
```

to this:

```
property TheStringsQ1Happy : {"Fabulous", "Great", "Alright", "Excited", "Not Bad", "", "Decent", "Fine", "Awesome", "Bored", "Cool", "Sad", "Fantastic", "Alright", "Good", "Ok"}
```

and you'll be good to go.

---

If you want a more permanent way to ensure you don't accidentally lose the new additions to this property, such as when you need to make any changes to the script in the future that will reset its value, then you'll need to store the information in an external file, which will serve as a sort of "dictionary" of vocabulary terms.

The simplest way to do this is to create a text file and put each item of the list on its own line, like this:

```
Fabulous
Great
Alright
Excited
...etc.
```

Save it as something like *HappyTerms.txt*, somewhere like your *Documents* folder, then change the variable declaration for `TheStringsQ1Happy` to this:

```
set TheStringsQ1Happy to the paragraphs of (read "/Users/%you%/Documents/HappyTerms.txt")
```

replacing *%you%* with the name of your *Home* folder in which your *Documents* folder lives.  In fact, it's a useful idea to put the path to this text file in its own variable definition just beforehand:

```
set VocabDictionary to "/Users/%you%/Documents/HappyTerms.txt"
set TheStringsQ1Happy to the paragraphs of (read VocabDictionary)
```

Finally, to make changes to this file and add new terms to it, immediately after this line:

```
if theResponseNotInVocabulary is "Yes" then set end of TheStringsQ1Happy to theResponse
```

simply add **either** these lines:

```
set AppleScript's text item delimiters to return
write (TheStringsQ1Happy as text) to VocabDictionary starting at 1
```

**OR** this line

```
write "\n" & theResponse to VocabDictionary starting at (get eof VocabDictionary) + 1
```

The first version overwrites the entire file with all the terms in the new list.  The second version simply appends the new addition to the end of the file.  You might want to experiment with both and get the file turning out the way you want it to, as you'll sneakily discover that one *might* give you a stray blank line in the file that results harmlessly in an empty string "" appearing in your list; whilst the other does not; but I'll leave you to figure out if and why this happens, and—should you really want it not to happen—how to prevent it.   Either way, it shouldn't cause you any problems.

If you have any other queries, post a comment and I'll back to you.  If this is helpful, don't forget to +1 my answer, and mark it as "correct" if solves your problem for you.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me using the latest version of Sierra

If this script is saved as an application,and you launch this new app... every time a new Item is added to the list, that new item will remain in the list every time you reopen the application.  However if you open the application again in script editor,to edit the code and re-save...  You will lose all of the values of the added list items And the whole cycle starts over again with the default list.

```
property TheStringsQ1Happy : {"Fabulous", "Great", "Alright", "Excited", "Not Bad", "", "Decent", "Fine", "Awesome", "Bored", "Cool", "Sad", "Fantastic", "Alright", "Good", "Ok"}

set theResponse to (display dialog "How Do You Feel Today?" default answer "" giving up after 25)

if text returned of theResponse is in TheStringsQ1Happy then
    display dialog "That's Great!"
else
    say "That term is not in my vocabulary. Would you like me to add it?" using "Tom" speaking rate 220
    set theResponseNotInVocabulary to display dialog "Add This Term" & " " & quote & text returned of theResponse & quote & " " & "To My Vocabulary?" buttons {"No", "Yes"} default button 2
    if the button returned of the result is "Yes" then
        if TheStringsQ1Happy does not contain text returned of theResponse then
            set end of TheStringsQ1Happy to text returned of theResponse
        end if
        return TheStringsQ1Happy
    end if
end if
```

Comment: Do you not check first to see if someone else hasn't already provided exactly the same solution before adding a repeat of an existing answer ?  I feel it's both an issue of etiquette and redundancy.

Comment: @CJK When I started  my solution to the OP, there were no answers yet.  After 30 minutes writing, tweaking and testing my code, I came back to post my answer and saw two other answers had been provided.  After reading those answers, I felt my answer had enough differences to warrant offering my solution as another answer.  My solution also went a step further and addressed the empty dialog boxes that were being displayed when running the OP’s code.  Also, no offense, but really… who are you to comment on my etiquette when my only reason for doing this is for nothing else but to help others?

Comment: I agree it's unfortunate that you spent the time you did focussing on an aspect of the code that wasn't related to the OP's original question, but the solution that's relevant is *identical* to one half of my answer, namely to define a property rather than a variable.  The issue of etiquette is completely unrelated to a desire to help someone, so I don't see the connection you're making.  But, I also don't want to descend into a petty argument, so I'll leave it there as I feel I've put my point across.  I'm happy for you to have have the last word on the matter.

Comment: I agree if my response was to change the variable to a property, that would be a duplicate of your answer and unnecessary.  However, looking at the big picture, the OP contained code that needed to be addressed.  Realizing the OP wasn't familiar with the benefits of declaring properties, chances were good he needed help in other areas also. In the spirit of helping,  I took his code and rewrote it to function correctly. If nothing else he’d be able to compare his code with my code, and would probably benefit from seeing the differences.

Comment: Frankly, I think that warrants a beer and a pat on the back LOL